# Nginx cannot find fullchain.pem from Letsencrypt certificate

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I generate certificates using `certbot certonly` for my app deployed on Ubuntu 22.04 (AWS EC2 instance). But when it comes to deploy nginx using Docker, I have an error :

```
2023/01/12 14:09:58 [emerg] 6#6: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.melodymaster.io/fullchain.pem": 
BIO_new_file() failed 
(SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.melodymaster.io/fullchain.pem','r') 
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

whereas the certificates are on the machine :

```
cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.melodymaster.io/fullchain.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII...
```

I already added all permissions to this file.

Here is my docker-compose.yml for nginx :

```
  nginx:
    image: docker.pkg.github.com/thomasroudil/melodymaster/melodymaster_dispatcher:${VERSION}
    build:
      context: ../dispatcher
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt'
    network_mode: host
```

and my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM nginx:1.17.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY mime.types /etc/nginx/mime.types
COPY conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d
CMD nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

with this `.conf` file :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.melodymaster.io;
    return 301 https://api.melodymaster.io$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen              443 ssl;
  server_name         api.melodymaster.io;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.melodymaster.io/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.melodymaster.io/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers         ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

  location ^~ / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4067$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Do you have any hints about why this error occurs ?

Comment: Are the files present at the specified folder?

Comment: Yes they are. This is why the probleme is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have the correct permissions for the folders and files.

Set the ownership of the folders and files to 'root' user `chown root:root`
Set the permission of the keys to `chmod 600`

Also **importantly**, check if the files are **Symlinked**. Run ls -al inside the folder and check if they are linked. If they are, copy them with a '`cp -L`' command

Try moving the certs to a folder like 'certs' outside letsencypt

Create a folder called 'etc/certs' and copy the cert files into that with the above copy command.

```
cp -L  /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.melodymaster.io/* /etc/certs/
```

From

```
ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.melodymaster.io/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.melodymaster.io/privkey.pem;
```

To

```
ssl_certificate     /etc/certs/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/privkey.pem;
```

Ultimately

```
chown -R root:root /etc/certs/
chmod -R 600 /etc/certs/*
```

Something like this. And when you go and check the files, they should be plain simple certificates without any Symlinks.